# Hibernate Criteria Pagination slow with or without Fetch.Join

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, pagination

I am working with Hibernate 3.6 pointing to Oracle. I have a Hibernate Criteria query with pagination and FetchJoins.

Whenever the query gets executed for the first time it takes around 26 seconds to read the table having 2400 rows/objects. I am displaying 20 results per page, so when I click on say page no 50, again it takes the same time i.e 26 seconds.

I have tried removing Fetch.Join and results are still the same. Can anyone suggest what could be the issue ?

Here is the code snippet :

```
Criteria searchCriteria = getSession().createCriteria(Employee.class);
searchCriteria.setMaxResults(20);
searchCriteria.setFirstResult((currentPage-1)* limit);

long start1  = System.currentTimeMillis();

Number totalCount = (Number) countCriteria.setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("empCode")).uniqueResult();

LOG.info("Count of records for distinct(empCode) :- " + totalCount);//2400 rows

long end1  = System.currentTimeMillis();

LOG.info("Time taken in Executing criteria query for empCode - ms - " + (end1-start1)+", sec - "+ (end1-start1)/1000);

List<WebReward> results = searchCriteria
            .setFetchMode("empDetails.empGroup", FetchMode.JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("address", FetchMode.JOIN)
.list();

LOG.info("Time taken in Executing searchCriteria query with FetchMode- ms - " + (end2 - end1)+", sec - "+  (end2 - end1)/1000); // 26 seconds
```

Note:- Employee.class is a view which have joins too.

Comment: Look at the generated SQL and run it in the SQL client using `explain` to see where the real cost is.

Comment: There are 3 different views inside that criteria and there are many queries that are getting generated in the logs. I am unable to identify it.

Comment: I have found that JPA with 3 or more joins are slow.

Comment: Just printed the final Criteria query and found that both the queries being executed are exactly same whether its on clicking on pagination link or the first search.

Comment: So I think the query results should be cached. whats the optimal way to do it ?